# Receber Lista na View. Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu estou com problema na Action Editar.

eu tenho um classe chamada ***ClienteEmpresa*** essa classe tem Uma coleção de Sistema. 
Por Exemplo: O Cliente **X** usa os sistemas **A**, **C** e **F**.

Meu problema é como apresentar esses sistema na View Editar.

Essa é minha View Get Editar

```
public ActionResult Editar(int? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
   ClienteEmpresa clienteEmpresa = db.ClienteEmpresaDb.Find(id);
    if (clienteEmpresa == null)
    {
      return HttpNotFound();
    }
      ViewBag.SistemasComerciais =  clienteEmpresa.TipoDeSistemas.ToList();
      ViewBag.RamoDeAtividade = clienteEmpresa.RamoAtividade;
      return View(clienteEmpresa);
}
```

Eu tentei enviar em uma viewBag, mas deu esse erro

> O item ViewData que possui a chave 'SistemasComerciais' é do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Smc.Dominio.Model.TipoDeSistemas,
>   Smc.Dominio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]',
>   mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable'.

Esse é o html que recebe essa lista.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:-34px; margin-top:17px;margin-bottom:11px;">
<label for="vat" class=" form-control-label">Tipo De Sistema</label>
@Html.DropDownList("SistemasComerciais", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Selecione..." })
</div>
```

Esse é o código da classe TipoDeSistemas:

```
public class TipoDeSistemas 
{ 
   [Key] 
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   [Required] 
   public string Descricao { get; set; } 

   public string Cod { get; set; } 

   [Required] 
   public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; } 

   public virtual ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> ClienteEmpresa { get; set; } 
}
```

Alguém sabe como eu posso mostrar essa lista de sistemas, que meu cliente usa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque você está usando `null` onde deveria passar o objeto com seus itens.

Tente assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SistemasComerciais", new SelectList(ViewBag.SistemasComerciais, "Id", "Nome"), 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Selecione..." })
```

Nesse exemplo eu estou inferindo que você possui uma classe (SistemasComerciais por exemplo) com as proprieades Id e Nome, se o nome das propriedades forem diferentes basta substituir onde está `"Id"` e `"Nome"` pelos nomes que você usa em suas propriedades.

A primeira propriedade (nesse exemplo `"Id"`) renderiza o atributo `value` no HTML e a segunda propriedade (nesse exemplo `"Nome"`) será renderizada como uma descrição:

```
<select class="standardSelect" id="SistemasComerciais" multiple="multiple" name="SistemasComerciais" placeholder="Selecione...">
   <option value="1">SistemaComercial a</option>
   <option value="2">SistemaComercial b</option>
   <option value="3">SistemaComercial c</option>
</select>
```

**Edição:**

---

Exemplo completo:

**Model:**

```
public class TipoDeSistemas
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult ViewBagComDropdown()
{
    List<TipoDeSistemas> lista = new List<TipoDeSistemas>()
    {
        new TipoDeSistemas { Id = 1, Descricao = "a" },
        new TipoDeSistemas { Id = 2, Descricao = "b" },
        new TipoDeSistemas { Id = 3, Descricao = "c" }
    };
    ViewBag.SistemasComerciais = lista;            
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("SistemasComerciais", new SelectList(ViewBag.SistemasComerciais, "Id", "Descricao", "Selecione... "), 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

Minha View renderizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agora deu essa mensagem. `DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' não contém uma propriedade com o nome 'Id'.`---- Porém eu tenho essa propriedade Id. 
é Id e Descricao que uso.

Comment: `public class TipoDeSistemas
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Cod { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> ClienteEmpresa { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Ok, adicionei o código da classe na pergunta. Bom quanto ao erro `DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' não contém uma propriedade com o nome 'Id'.` te aconselho a debugar seu código e verificar o retorno dessa propriedade após obter retorno na linha  `ViewBag.SistemasComerciais =  clienteEmpresa.TipoDeSistemas.ToList();`

Comment: Fiz aqui rapidinho um exemplo completo e adicionei para você na minha resposta.

Comment: Agora de certo \o/..obrigado!!...

Answer (score 1):

O `Html.Helper` para dropDownList é:

```
MvcHtmlString Html.DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectLestItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

e o tipo passado no `Viewbag` é uma `List`
Você pode ou enviar um `IEnumerable` ou popular o dropDown manualmente.

Comment: Não entendi muiito bem, tem como vc fazer esse helper ai, com esses dados aqui.
`@Html.DropDownList("SistemasComerciais", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Selecione..." })`

Comment: Tente passando os dados em um `IEnumerable` ao invés de uma `List`